# There is no top command in docker container

Tags: linux, docker, top

I try to deploy an app in docker container using `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0` image that need to have top command

when I try to run top command the following result shown:

```
bash: top: command not found
```

how can I install top command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I try to run following command inside docker container to search top command

```
$ apt-file search --regexp '/top$'
```

The result:

```
broctl: /usr/share/broctl/scripts/helpers/top
crossfire-maps: /usr/share/games/crossfire/maps/santo_dominion/magara/well/top
crossfire-maps-small: /usr/share/games/crossfire/maps/santo_dominion/magara/well/top
liece: /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/liece/styles/top
lxpanel: /etc/xdg/lxpanel/two_panels/panels/top
open-infrastructure-container-tools: /usr/lib/open-infrastructure/container/top
procps: /usr/bin/top
quilt: /usr/share/quilt/top
```

so I try to install procps using following command inside the docker container

```
$ apt install procps
```

Comment: And you didn't bother to tell us what the result of that command was or if you ran it INSIDE of the docker container or the docker host.  I am kinda guessing that this was run from the host.

Comment: worked by installing procps

Comment: This worked for me. If you get an error when you run `apt install procps` just restart your SSH connection to the Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably intentional - the docker philosophy is pretty much one application/process a container with whatever it needs to run.

You're unlikely to need a full set of userland tools in a container. If you do need to inspect the container itself, you can use [`docker top`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/top/) from the system running the docker instance instead.

Comment: I 'sort of' agree with you but *we* use them for everything.  Testing environments.. build environments.. whatever.. and these environments contain whatever tools are needed to get the job done for that container.  If you are talking about the containers we provide to customers.. yes, they are stripped, but that isn't the only way to use docker.